# How to merge 2 jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my jquery code and i want to merge these 2 functions into 1.

```
$("#first_name").change(function() {
  $('.showvalue').text("First Name Successfully Updated.");
});

$("#last_name").change(function() {
  $('.showvalue').text("last Name Successfully Updated.");
});
```

Comment: You need to be more clear in what you want to do. Are you looking at some sort of generic function to handle all .change() events?

Comment: Please pick one of the answers as the accepted answer by pressing the "✔" button if you think your question has been answered by it.

Answer (score 2):

This will show "First Name Successfully Updated." for the first name and "Last Name Successfully Updated." for the last name:

```
var names = ['First', 'Last'];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var name = names[i];
  $("#" + name.toLowerCase() + "_name").change(function() {
    $('.showvalue').text(name + " Name Successfully Updated.");
  });
}
```

So this keeps your capitalization of the field names.

This solution is also easy to extend with more fields.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the selectors and then in event handler check the id in order to determine which message to use:

```
$("#first_name, #last_name").change(function() {
   var prefix = this.id === 'first_name' ? 'First' :'Last';
   $('.showvalue').text( prefix + " Name Successfully Updated.");
});
```

Comment: Works :). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You may reusing the same function in javascript for elements using CLASS selector

(example class: changeTrigger).

```
<p>First Name <input type="text" id="first_name" class="changeTrigger" data-ref="First Name"/></p>
<p>Last Name <input type="text" id="last_name" class="changeTrigger" data-ref="Last Name"/></p>
<p class='showvalue'></p>
```

Second, define a function to handle multi elements in same CLASS

```
$(".changeTrigger").change(function(){

  //You may use data-ref to attach "FIELD NAME" on element.
  var refName = $(this).data("ref");

  $('.showvalue').text(refName + " Successfully Updated.");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3f8505q/